# Lenovo Yoga 2 11 with no wi-fi (soft block removed)

Tags: wireless, yoga-2

I installed Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04 LTS on a Lenovo Yoga 2 11 and noticed I had no wi-fi option, only networking (usually I see "enable wi-fi" too.)

`rfkill list all` resulted in only a soft block and after running `sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop` the soft block was removed.

The trouble is that I don't know were to go from here as I still do not have wifi. All of tutorials/docs I have found address what to do if you have a hard block.

Comment: What wireless card? Please add the result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corperation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [1424:4365], Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wired connection and `uname -r` shows that you are using a 3.13 kernel you just need to `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` and reboot.  If `uname -r` shows that you are using a 3.16 kernel, then you need to go http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/bcmwl-kernel-source to download it

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing the problem by manually downloading `bcmwl-kernel-source` and its dependency `dkms` on another computer.  I transfered the packages via usb and after I installed them using `sudo dpkg -i` I was able to access the internet just fine.